# Issue encountered while trying to run a process in Apache Airflow using Docker

Tags: docker, airflow, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

Even though it ran successfully locally. The process involves using the pdfkit module directly, with the following code:

`pdfkit.from_string(text_content, filename, options={"enable-local-file-access": ""`})

```
However, when executing this code within the Docker container, I received the following error:

raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, error_msg))
OSError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error: QPainter::begin(): Returned false. Exit with code 1, due to an unknown error.
```